# How to read a yaml node array into std::vector

Tags: yaml-cpp

A total noob with yaml-cpp. I have a node something like this:

```
numbers : [1,2,3,4,5]
```

In the CPP file, I want to parse into a vector:

```
std::vector<int> vi = node["numbers"];
```

This doesn't work. I can't find any documentation other than the tutorial- and it isn't covered in the tutoral.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yaml-cpp already has overloads for standard container types, so the `as<T>()` function works here:

```
std::vector<int> vi = node["numbers"].as<std::vector<int>>();
```